# Three-statement biconditional

Tags: logic, equivalence-relations

If you want to show that $$p\iff q\iff r,$$  do you then have to show that
$p\iff q , p\iff r , q\iff r ?$

Comment: You can omit "$p\iff r$" because of the transitivity of "iff". You can also show $p\implies q$ , $q\implies r$ and $r\implies p$

Comment: Are you using the $\Leftrightarrow$ as an expression of equivalence (in which case we typically interpret an expression like this as saying that $p$, $q$, and $r$ are all equivalent to each other, or do you use as the logical connective called the material biconditional? (more typically written as $p \leftrightarrow q \leftrightarrow r$)?  Because if the latter, then you are dealing with a single logic expression that would be true if and only if either $p$, $q$, and $r$ are all true, or if exactly one of them is true.

Comment: Re: Peter's comment. Just because Y implies Z does not generally mean that writing a proof of Y is the same as writing a proof of Z, because to complete a proof of Z you want also to at least observe the `Y implies Z` relationship.  Similarly, just because `(p⟺q) and (q⟺r)` implies `(p⟺q) and (q⟺r) and (p⟺r)` does not in itself mean that the former and latter require the exact same proof. More to the point: `(p⟺q) and (q⟺r)` and `p⟺q⟺r` require the exact same proof because they are literal translations of each other, and neither requires proving `p⟺r` because neither is asserting that `p⟺r`!

Comment: I thought of a nice example today, where there are four equivalent statements, and we typically show that each of the six equivalences $X\iff Y$ holds not by showing all six, but by showing only that $a\implies b, b\implies c, c\implies d, $ and $d\implies a$.

Comment: The example is: If a language is represented by a regular expression, it can be recognized by an NFA with $\epsilon$-transitions. If a language can be recognized by an NFA with $\epsilon$-transitions, it can be recognized by an NFA _without_ $\epsilon$-transitions. If a language can be recognized by an NFA without  $\epsilon$-transitions, it can be recognized by a DFA. And if a language can be recognized by a DFA, it can be represented by a regular expression. See [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Equivalent_formalisms) for more details.

Comment: Another typical example is: the principle of mathematical induction implies the principle of strong mathematical induction.  The principle of strong mathematical induction implies the well-ordering theorem.  And the well-ordering theorem implies the principle of mathematical induction. And this is usually how we would prove that all three are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Three-statement biconditional
>
> If you want to show that $$p\iff q\iff r,\tag1$$  do you then have to show that
> $p\iff q , p\iff r , q\iff r ?$

I'm replying tangentially to the intent of your question. Here are three reasonable ways to read sentence $(1),$ with each main connective coloured red:
$$(p\iff q)\color\red\iff r\tag A$$
$$p\color\red\iff (q\iff r)\tag B$$
$$(p\iff q)\color\red{\text{ and }}(q\iff r).\tag C$$

Readings A and B are equivalent to each other. However, neither is equivalent to the common mathematics reading, C; you can see this by supposing that $p,q,r$ are all false.

By calling sentence $(1)$ a three-statement conditional, you are almost certainly adopting reading C while observing its consequence that `p⟺r` (here, your three statements refer to the two conjuncts of C and `p⟺r`); therein lies your answer: to prove that reading C is true does not ***require*** proving that the conjunction C itself ***as well as some consequence of it*** are true. (After all, surely it is clear that proving C does not ***require*** additionally proving its consequence `p⟺(q∧r)` either.)

Comment: Good answer! :)